# Перезапись глобальной переменной одним из потоков

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, threading

Есть некий список, с которым на чтение бесконечно работает поток. Этот список нужно изредка обновлять «на лету». Обновление я делаю вторым потоком по таймеру. Что будет, если первому потоку приспичит прочесть список в тот момент, когда он обновляется вторым потоком? Ошибка доступа? Пустая переменная? (`[]`) Как этого и сбежать?

```
import threading
from random import randint


MY_LIST = [randint(0, 9), randint(0, 9), randint(0, 9)]


def main():
    while True:
        print(MY_LIST)


def update():
    MY_LIST = [randint(0, 9), randint(0, 9), randint(0, 9)]
    threading.Timer(60.0, update).start()

threading.Thread(target="main", name="mainthd").start()
threading.Thread(target="update", name="upd").start()
```

Comment: Используйте стандартные средства языка, наиболее подходящие для вашего случая. Можете вот это: <https://docs-python.ru/standart-library/modul-threading-python/klass-rlock-modulja-threading/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ зависит от того, как именно происходит обновление и доступ к переменной.

Простое обновление присваиванием, как в вопросе и одно чтение переменной, не вызовет никаких проблем. Присваивание переменной в питоне атомарно. Это значит, что до присваивания второй поток при чтении будет видеть старое значение. После присваивания - сразу увидит новое.

Больше проблем может возникнуть, если пишущий поток будет модифицировать список не одной операцией (например делать вставки и/или удаления), в этом случае читатель сможет видеть эти промежуточные результаты, если будет читать из переменной параллельно с писателем.

Но повторюсь, что если сначала подготовить список и потом одной операцией его присвоить, то с записью проблем нет, т.к. она атомарна.

Проблема может возникнуть у читателя, если он не будет достаточно осторожен. В примере выше проблем нет - переменная читается один раз и прочитанное значение (ссылка на объект списка) передается в функцию `print`. Проблема возникнет, если читатель будет использовать код типа такого:

```
for i in range(0, len(MY_LIST)):
   print(MY_LIST[i])
```

Тут проблема в том, что между двумя итерациями цикла может вклиниться пишущий поток и перезаписать значения `MY_LIST`. Тогда читатель увидит изменение списка, первая половина старого, вторая - из нового. А в случае, если длина уменьшилась, то может быть попытка обращения по индексу за пределами нового списка.

Если такая итерация нужно, то это легко обойти. Нужно сохранить ссылку на объект и дальше работать с тем самым объектом не пробуя читать переменную, которая может потенциально измениться и указывать уже на новый объект:

```
my_list_reference = MY_LIST
for i in range(0, len(my_list_reference)):
   print(my_list_reference[i])
```

В этом случае переменная одна и атомарность присваивания не требует ручной синхронизации используя блокровки. Если бы переменных было несколько и состояние описывается ими совокупно, то нужно или при каждой операции чтения и записи получать [блокировку](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#lock-objects) или хранить все состояние в одном объекте и изменение делать путем создания нового объекта с новыми значениями и присваиванием одной переменной:

```
@dataclass
class SharedState:
   some_var: list[int]
   other_var: str
     

STATE = SharedState([randint(0, 9), randint(0, 9), randint(0, 9)], "something")


def main():
    global state
    while True:
        state = STATE
        print(state.some_var)
        print(state.other_var)


def update():
    # важно создавать новые объекты, а не модифицировать старые
    MY_LIST = StaredState([randint(0, 9), randint(0, 9), randint(0, 9)], "other")
    threading.Timer(60.0, update).start()
```